# Problems with .CountAsync() when counting a query that has been grouped and selected

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Okay so I'm stuck,

My query looks something like this

```
var query = db.SomeTableInDb
              .Include(x =>x...)
              .Where(x => x...)
              .OrderByDescending(x => x.On)
              .ThenBy(x => x.Id)
              .GroupBy(p => p.SomeOtherId)
              .Select(p => p.FirstOrDefault())
              .AsQueryable();
         
var total = await query.CountAsync();
```

The query works just fine and I get my results back but upon trying to count the results from the IQueryable it gives me this exception.

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyu52.png)

I've tested the query without grouping and selecting and then .CountAsync() works fine.

Any ideas of what may be causing this are welcomed!

Comment: Try to use 'First' instead of 'FirstOrDefault' - every group contains at least one element.

Comment: I presume this is using EF. If you are going to be returning the results anyway, then you can avoid the issue by changing query to a list and counting the items in the list which will work. If you are not going to be returning the results, then you can simplify the query by removing the .Include, .OrderByDescending, .ThenBy and the .Select (but it is really only the .Select that causes the problem)

Comment: Show full query. It is not enough to understand what happened. Maybe parameter is wrong or mapping or even worse EF Core bug.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Not the OP, but I thought this was a known limitation with EF Group by. See [https://dotnetfiddle.net/axucSQ](https://dotnetfiddle.net/axucSQ) for a very much simplified version of the issue.

Comment: @sgmoore, Yes, looks like a EF Core bug.

Comment: What number are you looking for?  That should give you just the number of items in the first subgroup.

Answer (score -1):

Wait, ignore what I just said in the comment above.  It returns the count of subgroups (with the full query giving the first record in each subgroup).

I tried to reproduce it using the Northwind database, and linq2sql:

```
var query = Customers
//            .Include(x => x...)
              .Where(x => x.Country == "USA")
              .OrderByDescending(x => x.PostalCode)
              .ThenBy(x => x.City)
              .GroupBy(p => p.Region)
              .Select(p => p.FirstOrDefault())
              .AsQueryable();

var total =  query.Count();

total.Dump();
query.Dump();
```

total = 8, which is correct.

Looking at the exception, the error occurs in the processing of a Select, in which you appear to have only one, so it would seem that the `p` is somehow `null` there.

Comment: This is using Linq2sql, but OP is using EF.